# cmd.exe does not show up when it is from AIR(AS3) invoked

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, flash, air, cmd

When I use AIR to invoke cmd.exe, it doesn't show up, but it appears in Task-Manager. When I pass parameter to cmd.exe, it doesn't react. The code has no problem with invoking notepad.exe or wscript.exe.(There is a button named btn on the stage) Here is my code:

```
import flash.desktop.NativeProcess;
import flash.desktop.NativeProcessStartupInfo;
import flash.filesystem.File;
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, invokeCmd);
function invokeCmd(e:MouseEvent):void{
    if(NativeProcess.isSupported){
        btn.label="NativeProcess supported";
        var info:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
        info.executable = new File("C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe");
        var processArg:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
        processArg.push("start dir");
        info.arguments = processArg;
        var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
        process.start(info);
    }
}
```

Comment: AIR is presumably hiding the console window; more often than not that's what you want when launching a subprocess.  If you make the command something like `cmd /c start cmd` it might work.

Comment: You are right! Thanks! But does it mean, that the hidden cmd.exe (without `cmd /c start cmd`)should work if I pass parameters to it? But it doesn't. And actually I don't want it to show up, I just want to run a bat file using cmd.exe...

Comment: I think I have got it. `cmd /c start location of xyz.bat` Thank you!

Comment: If you don't want the command window to show up, why are you asking why it doesn't show up??  Anyway, if an invisible window is OK, you don't need to use `start`, just say `cmd /c xyz.bat`.